# on_presence_update doesnt seem to work discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm using commands.autoshardedbot, with intents set to

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True
intents.guilds = True
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True
```

and I have a listener in the cog class I want to use to send an alert to a channel whenever a specific person goes offline, code looks like this

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_presence_update(self, before: discord.Member, after: discord.Member):
        if after.id == id and before.status != Status.offline and after.status == Status.offline: #from discord import Status
            print(before.status, after.status, Status.offline, Status.online) #this doesnt ever print
            channel = await bot.fetch_channel() #id with channel to send alert to 
            await channel.send("test")
```

id is an int that has my discord user id
I have no idea what i'm doing wrong here, in the dev portal the presence gateway is also enabled

well I added the intents.presences = True, didnt work, tried printing the statuses for debugging, didnt work, perhaps i should be comparing `after` to a `user = await bot.fetch_user()` and `str(before.status)` to `'offline'`?

```
@commands.command()
async def whatstatus(self, ctx: Context, user: discord.Member = None):
        if user == None:
            await ctx.send("mention someone idiot")
        else:
            await ctx.send(user.status)
```

this code works perfectly fine, returns online, idle, offline etc., yet

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_presence_update(self, before: discord.Member, after: discord.Member):
        channel = await bot.fetch_channel(949000882853400699)
        await channel.send(f"{before}, {before.status}, {after}, {after.status}")
```

still doesnt work
`on_member_update` doesn't get called when someone's status changes, as the [discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=presence#discord.on_presence_update) says

Answer (score 0):

alright it seems to work if I set the listener name to "on_presence_update"

```
    @commands.Cog.listener(name='on_presence_update')
    async def somethingidk(self, before: discord.Member, after: discord.Member):
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).